# When I tried to add data to database by clicking on a button in android studio and there was a crash of my program

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I try to add data to database by clicking on a button in android studio my program crashes.

```
package com.example.ganesha.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText StudentName,StudentRollno;
  // String selectedmess;
 Context context = this;
 StudentDbHelper studentDbHelper;
 SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource    (this,R.array.mess,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String selectedmess=spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});

}



public void addDetail(View view)
{
  String name = StudentName.getText().toString();
  String rollno = StudentRollno.getText().toString();
  studentDbHelper = new StudentDbHelper(context);
  sqLiteDatabase = studentDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  studentDbHelper.addInfo(name,rollno,sqLiteDatabase);
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"One row data saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
studentDbHelper.close();

 }


 }
```

The above is mainactivity.java file

2. Databasefirst.java file

   ```
    package com.example.ganesha.myapplication;


     public class Databasefirst {

     public static abstract class studentinfo{
     public static final String STUDENT_NAME="Student Name";//column name
     public static final String STUDENT_ROLLNO="Student Roll no";//column name
     // public static final String MESS_NAME="Mess Alloted";//column name
    public static final String MESS_DETAILS="Mess Details";//table name
     }

     }
   ```

3.Studentdbhelper.java
        package com.example.ganesha.myapplication;

```
     import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;
     public class StudentDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
     private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "STUDENTINFO.DB";
     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
     private static final String CREATE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+
                 Databasefirst.studentinfo.MESS_DETAILS+"("+Databasefirst.studentinfo.STUDENT_NAME+" TEXT,"+Databasefirst.studentinfo.STUDENT_ROLLNO+" TEXT);";

      public StudentDbHelper(Context context){
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
      Log.e("DATABASE_OPERATION ","Database created");
     }
   //called when table doesnt exist in the first place
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.e("DATABASE_OPERATION ","Table created");
}
public void addInfo(String name,String number,SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Databasefirst.studentinfo.STUDENT_NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(Databasefirst.studentinfo.STUDENT_ROLLNO,number);
    //contentValues.put(Databasefirst.studentinfo.MESS_NAME,messname);
    db.insert(Databasefirst.studentinfo.MESS_DETAILS,"null",contentValues);
    Log.e("DATABASE_OPERATION ","row inserted");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
 }
```

And I am getting the following log message whenever I enter the submit button in the app
            07-17 10:27:20.415 2841-2841/com.example.ganesha.myapplication I/art:        Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
            07-17 10:27:20.506 2841-2841/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/System:        ClassLoader referenced unknown   path: /data/app/com.example.ganesha.myapplication-1/lib/x86
           07-17 10:27:22.897 2841-2841/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ganesha.myapplication-1/lib/x86
          07-17 10:27:24.273 2841-2841/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/art:   Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter  (android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-         private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
         07-17 10:27:24.529 2841-2941/com.example.ganesha.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

```
                                                                                          [ 07-17 10:27:24.540  2841: 2841 D/         ]
                                                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaa55420, tid 2841


                                                                                        [ 07-17 10:27:24.677  2841: 2941 D/         ]
                                                                                           HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3fed310,       tid 2941
```

07-17 10:27:24.691 2841-2941/com.example.ganesha.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
                   07-17 10:27:24.733 2841-2941/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
              07-17 10:27:24.733 2841-2941/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa031be0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
               07-17 10:27:28.059 2841-2847/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.381ms
               07-17 10:27:35.287 2841-2841/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
                 07-17 10:27:37.181 2841-2941/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
              07-17 10:27:37.181 2841-2941/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaaa7ff60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
              07-17 10:27:39.284 2841-2941/com.example.ganesha.myapplication E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4017550
              07-17 10:27:39.296 2841-2941/com.example.ganesha.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xaa0a5c00 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle 0xaa37ce10
             07-17 10:27:41.790 2841-2841/com.example.ganesha.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
                                                                                           --------- beginning of crash
```

07-17 10:27:41.790 2841-2841/com.example.ganesha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              Process: com.example.ganesha.myapplication, PID: 2841
                                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual   method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.example.ganesha.myapplication.MainActivity.addDetail(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
07-17 10:27:44.735 2841-2841/com.example.ganesha.myapplication I/Process:    Sending signal. PID: 2841 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

As your Logcat say

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference

As you have declare the `EditText` variable global but not Initliaze it inside your `OnCreate` method so that it can give you `NullPointerExeception`

so inside your `OnCreate` Method initialize it with below way

```
StudentName = (EditText)findViewByid(R.id.StudentNameId);    
StudentRollno = (EditText)findViewByid(R.id.StudentRollNo);
```

> Note : As you not post the xml file so that i give random name of the
>   `EditText` `Id` field.